# JavaFX FXML Center BorderPane bottom

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have a `Button` which I would like to put to the bottom of my BorderPane and center it. I want to achieve this with `FXML`.

This is the bottom of my BorderPane:

```
        <bottom>
            <Button>
                <text>
                    Center this button
                </text>
            </Button>
        </bottom>
```

The full `FXML` (without imports):

```
<BorderPane id="BorderPane" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
        <top>
            <HBox>
                <BorderPane.margin>
                    <Insets left="15" right="15" top="15"/>
                </BorderPane.margin>
                <spacing>
                    5
                </spacing>
                <Label>
                    <padding>
                        <Insets top="5" right="5"/>
                    </padding>
                    <text>
                        Y-Axis:
                    </text>
                </Label>
                <TextField>
                    <text>
                        10
                    </text>
                </TextField>

                <Label>
                    <padding>
                        <Insets top="5" left="15" right="5"/>
                    </padding>
                    <text>
                        X-Axis:
                    </text>
                </Label>
                <TextField>
                    <text>
                        10
                    </text>
                </TextField>
            </HBox>
        </top>

        <bottom>
            <Button>
                <text>
                    Center this button
                </text>
            </Button>
        </bottom>
```

The result:

[image]

Is there any Tag to achieve this with FXML? Or do I have to do this with JAVA?
Thank you.

Comment: One thing you can do is put a `StackPane` in the bottom then add the `Button` to the `StackPane`.

Comment: The other thing you can do is set `Alignment` to `CENTER` for the bottom.

Comment: @Sedrick thanks, if I add an alignment tag to the button the result is the same. I will try the idea with the stackpane.

Comment: @Sedrick StackPane worked. Good idea. could you answer this question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `BorderPane.alignment`:

```xml
<bottom>
    <Button BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <text>
            Center this button
        </text>
    </Button>
</bottom>
```

Comment: Wow simple as that! Weird that this wasnt asked before. Where did you find the solution for this? Thanks!

Comment: Could you please tell me where you got this information from?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html#setAlignment-javafx.scene.Node-javafx.geometry.Pos- and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#static_property_elements (FXML)